# Bulk.getOperations() in MongoDB Node driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I'd like to view the results of a bulk operation, specifically to know the IDs of the documents that were updated. I understand that this information is made available through the [`Bulk.getOperations()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.getOperations/) method. However, it doesn't appear that this method is available through the MongoDB NodeJS library (at least, the one I'm using).

Could you please let me know if there's something I'm doing wrong here:

```js
const bulk = db.collection('companies').initializeOrderedBulkOp()
const results = getLatestFinanicialResults() // from remote API

results.forEach(result => 
  bulk.find({ 
    name: result.companyName, 
    report: { $ne: result.report } 
  }).updateOne([
    { $unset: 'prevReport' },
    { $set: { prevReport: '$report' } },
    { $unset: 'report' },
    { $set: { report: result.report } }
  ]))

await bulk.execute()
await bulk.getOperations() // <-- fails, undefined in Typescript library
```

I get a static IDE error:

> Uncaught TypeError: bulk.getOperations is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to view the results of a bulk operation, specifically to know the IDs of the documents that were updated

As of currently (MongoDB server v6.x) There is no methods to return IDs for updated documents from a bulk operations (only insert and upsert operations). However, there may be a work around depending on your use case.

The manual that you linked for [Bulk.getOperations()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.getOperations/#bulk.getoperations--) is for [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/), which is a MongoDB Shell application. If you look into the [source code for `getOperations()`](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongosh/blob/v1.6.0/packages/shell-api/src/bulk.ts#L226-L229) in `mongosh`, it's just a convenient wrapper for `batches'. The method` batches` returns a list of operations sent for the bulk execution.

As you are utilising *ordered* bulk operations, MongoDB executes the operations serially. If an error occurs during the processing of one of the write operations, MongoDB will return without processing any remaining write operations in the list.

Depending on the use case, if you modify the `bulk.find()` part to contain a search for `_id` for example:

```js
bulk.find({"_id": result._id}).updateOne({$set:{prevReport:"$report"}});
```

You should be able to see the `_id` value of the operation in the `batches`, i.e.

```js
await batch.execute(); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(batch.batches));
```

Example output:

```json
{
 "originalZeroIndex":0,
 "currentIndex":0,
 "originalIndexes":[0],
 "batchType":2,
 "operations":[{"q":{"_id":"634354787d080d3a1e3da51f"},
                "u":{"$set":{"prevReport":"$report"}}], 
 "size":0,
 "sizeBytes":0
}
```

For additional information, you could also retrieve the [BulkWriteResult](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.10/classes/BulkWriteResult.html). For example, the [getLastOp](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.10/classes/BulkWriteResult.html#getLastOp) to retrieve the last operation (in case of a failure)

Comment: Thanks alot Wan! `batch.batches` looks like what I'm after. Is there a way to know which rows the `updateOne` operation was executed on? Or is it simply the case that `batch.batches` returns the results that pass through the `find` filter?

Comment: I really just need the `symbol` of the updated documents.. (The symbol is unique, so if it returns results based on the query operation, that's fine by me)

Comment: The crucial part, which might not have been obvious from my post, is that I'm not updating ALL records -- just the ones where the reports have changed (`report: { $ne: result.report }`)

Comment: Hi @FloatingRock, could you filter out the documents that you don't want to update from the method `getLatestFinancialResults()` ? so within the loop you're batching only operations to be updated.

Comment: Ok, will do. It requires one more DB query, so was hoping to avoid that :) Thanks!